# Solve the ODE to get the expression of theta(z)

Tags: calculus

can someone help me to solve this Ordinary Differential Equation? If there is no symbolic solution exist, how can I get a numerical solution? thanks for help

\begin{gather}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\left( (1+\lambda \alpha z) \theta(z)+\frac{z(1+\lambda z)}{1-\gamma}\theta'(z)\right)^{1-\frac{1}{\gamma}} }{1-\frac{1}{\gamma}}+\frac{\mu^2\left(\theta(z)+\frac{z}{1-\gamma}\theta'(z)\right)^2 }{2 \sigma^2 \left(-\gamma \theta(z)+2 z \theta'(z)+\frac{z^2}{1-\gamma}\theta''(z)\right)} \\
&+\left( \frac{\beta}{1-\gamma}-r+\alpha \delta\right) \theta(z)-\frac{(r+\delta)z}{1-\gamma}\theta'(z)=0
\end{aligned}
\right. 
\end{gather}

Comment: Is there anyone who can go anywhere about this equation? Any comments will be helpful for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: I still wish than someone can lend me a hand with this problem.